# Support Gujarati fonts in recycler view in android

Tags: android, fonts, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on an android application which needs Gujarati font support. I have tried the typeface method but all in vain. I tried to find the solution on internet but didn't quiet get the solution.
I am using recycler view  in which I need to display the text view using Gujarati fonts.
I kindly request you to help me with this.

Thanx in advance .... :):)

Here is the method i used to add custom gujarati fonts in the ViewHolder method of RecyclerView

```
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);


        mNameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/guj.ttf");

        this.mNameTextView.setTypeface(tf);
        this.mNameTextView.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);


    }
```

Comment: Please show whatever you have tried..

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the Solution. All i needed was the official google NotoSansGujarati font which can be downloaded from the given link.
https://www.google.com/get/noto/

public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

```
        mNameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf");

        this.mNameTextView.setTypeface(tf);
        this.mNameTextView.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Android 5.0 (Lollipop)**, Google has added fonts.

The fonts are called **Noto Sans Gujarati** and **Noto Sans Gujarati UI**.

As you're working on an application, that has to be compatible for all the Android Versions, you have to root the particular device for that to work on.

[Reference 1](http://www.anirdesh.com/gujarati/add-gujarati-font-in-android.php)

[Reference 2](http://forum.droidarena.in/Thread-How-to-Install-Read-Write-Regional-Language-Fonts-on-any-Android-Phone)

Comment: I want to embed gujarati fonts along with android app so that it supports all devices :(